# Not able to clear the last data-source of GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

First, I am selecting all records on page-load like this:

```
OleDbCommand objCmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM MyTable", mycon);
objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
DataTable dtTemp = new DataTable();
OleDbDataReader rd = objCommand.ExecuteReader();
if (rd.HasRows)
{
    dtTemp.Load(rd);
    gvTemp.DataSource = dtTemp;
    gvTemp.DataBind();
}
```

In GridView(`gvTemp`), I am passing `MemID` in `CommandArgument` like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" ItemStyle-Width="80px">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnStart" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("MemID") %>' CommandName="Start">Start</asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

So when I click on `Start`, `gvTemp_RowCommand` is fired and I want to get `CommandArgument` (`MemID`). So I am doing this to achieve it:

```
protected void gvTemp_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Start")
    {
        Response.Redirect("AddMem.aspx?MemID=" + e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    }
}
```

This work fine. But problem is here.
When user search for a particular record, I reload `gvTemp` like this:

```
OleDbCommand objCmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MemID = ?", mycon);
objCmd.Parameters.Add(myParam); 
objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
DataTable dtTemp = new DataTable();
OleDbDataReader rd = objCommand.ExecuteReader();
if (rd.HasRows)
{
    dtTemp.Load(rd);
    gvTemp.DataSource = dtTemp;
    gvTemp.DataBind();
}
```

Executing this query, I am getting only one record. And when I click on `Start`, `gvTemp_RowCommand` is fired. But I am getting `e.CommandArgument` of old DataSource. (i.e. The top 1 `MemID` of `SELECT * FROM MyTable`). So before binding actual DataSource I clear the GridView like this:

```
gvTemp.DataSource = null;
gvTemp.DataBind();
gvTemp.DataSource = dtTemp;
gvTemp.DataBind();
```

But still I am getting `e.CommandArgument` of old DataSource. So what am I missing? Or is there any alternative method to achieve the same?

Comment: what is the value of `myParam` that you are passing in `objCmd.Parameters.Add(myParam);`?

Comment: try Refresh() or .ResetBindings   may it solve

Comment: @prashanth I am getting it's value from method arguments.

Comment: @GyanChandraSrivastava Is't `Refresh()` and `ResetBinding()` are methods of `DataGridView`. I have `GridView` here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On every button click a postback occurs and the page load event occurs so in your case this might be the reason why previous data source is being loaded. so you must check IsPostBack condition.

Try something like this:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
   //Your code or method for selecting all records.
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simple remove the `Response.Redirect(itself)` and use methods and properties instead?

```
private string MemID{
    get { return (String)ViewState["MemID"]; }
    set { ViewState["MemID"] = value; }
}

private void BindGrid()
{
    // copy your sql,datasource and databind stuff here, use the MemID property for the parameter
}

protected void gvTemp_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Start")
    {
        MemID = e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        BindGrid();
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, `AddMem.aspx` is another page. Where I want to pass `MemID`